# Does one of these programs have an advantage over the other? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Having learned some Javascript from CodeAcademy, I wanted to try some exercises to test my knowledge. 
 The exercise was this
Write a JavaScript function which will take an array of numbers stored and find the second lowest and second greatest numbers, respectively. - See more at: http://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-functions-exercises.php#EDITOR

My function was this

```
  function checker(array) {
       narray = array.sort();
       console.log(narray);
       console.log(narray[1] + "," + narray[array.length - 2]);
   }
   checker([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Their function was this

```
function Second_Greatest_Lowest(arr_num)
{
  arr_num.sort(function(x,y)
           {
           return x-y;
           });
  var uniqa = [arr_num[0]];
  var result = [];

  for(var j=1; j<arr_num.length; j++)
  {
    if(arr_num[j-1] !== arr_num[j])
    {
      uniqa.push(arr_num[j]);
    }
  }

  result.push(uniqa[1],uniqa[uniqa.length-2]);

  return result.join(',');

}

alert(Second_Greatest_Lowest([1,2,3,4,5]));
```

Do you see any reason why the second option would be better?

Comment: Compare `checker([1,1,2,3,3])` with `Second_Greatest_Lowest([1,1,2,3,3])`.

Comment: For starters your goal is to learn a new programming language. One good way of doing it, is trying to implement basic things like sort yourself. Big part of this exercises point is lost if you use javascripts native sort method.

Comment: I do get that I could try to do it myself.. but some of their exercises use sort anyways.. so its not like I feel like I should use it. Although I do agree that knowing multiple ways to do things is always helpful.

Comment: @s3ib: the "reference" implementation also uses the native `Array#sort`, that's not the task here.

Comment: @Chris: I like yours better. If there was a requirement to only deal with unique values which you haven't told us about, then there's simpler ways to solve this.

Comment: It should be noted that neither of these methods will work on an array of size 1 or less.

Comment: Well yes, @PrestonS ,but that wasn't part of the exercise.

Comment: @ChrisJones Its every programmers responsibility to identify points of failure in their code and fix them.

Comment: Well yes if I am actually programming something you would, but otherwise, many of those checks are trivial to type up.

Comment: @ChrisJones I get where your coming from, but since your learning JS I wanted to point out that the code will fail in this case.

Comment: It might be fine for tutorial code, but their technique for removing duplicates from  a sorted array seem pretty verbose.  The could probably do the same thing with something like `arr_num = arr_num.reduce(function(arr, el) {if (arr[arr.length - 1] !== el) arr.push(el); return arr;}, [arr_num[0]]);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted, their answer wants the 2nd unique number and it is rather inefficient as well.

There are two differences between your solution and theirs:

- sorting function
- uniqueness

The implicit sorting function is a natural sort. This means that the objects are converted to strings and compared as strings:

```
[1, 2, 3, 11].sort() // [1, 11, 2, 3] 
[1, 2, 3, 11].sort(function(a,b){ return a-b }); // [1, 2, 3, 11]
```

The second difference, the uniqueness of the numbers. Your solution gives the number on the second position in the array, while theirs gives the number with the second lowest value:

```
[1,1,2] // Your solution: 1,1
[1,1,2] // Their solution: 2,1
```

While you can argue that it is not required, that is a matter of definition.

Either way, an improvement could be made in their solution as well to make it more efficient, though not as readable:

```
function getNumbers(arr) {
  if (!arr.length) throw new Error('arr has no items');
  arr = arr.slice().sort(function(a,b){ return a-b }); // copy and sort the array
  for (var i=0; arr[i] === arr[0]; i++);
  if (i === arr.length) { // all numbers are identical
    return [arr[0], arr[0]];
  }
  var a = arr[i]; // second lowest number

  i = arr.length-1;
  var b = arr[i];
  while (arr[i] === b) i--;
  return [a, arr[i]];
}

// usage 
getNumbers([2,3,1,1,1,6,4,5,6,1,11]) //[2, 6]
```

As you can see, once you found the number you're interested in, you no longer iterate through the sorted array. Compared to the solution that computes an array of unique numbers, this one is far more efficient, especially for large arrays.

Comment: Thanks!!! It is nice to see other solutions that might be more efficient. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisJones It's not only more efficient. The first part of the answer shows the cases where your solution fails completely. `checker([1,2,3,4,5,11]) // 11,4` is an example.

Comment: My solution is slightly inaccurate as well, because i should throw an errorif there is only 1 number in the array ([1,1,1]), but instead i chose to return [1,1] for that case. I marked the point in the code where that case is considered and it can be improved.

Comment: Yes, I see that. One question I do have is, for reading sake, could you not define the function outside of the slice().sort() then just call it there?

Comment: @ChrisJones Yes, you certainly can. It's a bad habit of mine to define anonymous functions for these situations on SO.

Comment: One question I do have is that I am somewhat vague on the how the function(a,b) part plays into it all. Is there a name for that technique so that I can kind of look it up. I really like to wrap my head around something so that I can understand it intuitively. I guess I just don't get where the a,b come from.

Comment: @ChrisJones [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). sort gets as parameter a function that for ane two arguments returns which one is bigger. `a` and `b` are the names i gave to those arguments, the CodeAcademy code has the same function, but with `x` and `y` as parameters.

Comment: THANKS!! I see what I didn't get now.. and feel silly. Sometimes things are familiar but for some reason I can't wrap my brain around them, Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

No. Your function is just better. Really. 
Reason is that on w3resource.com wants to show you how it should work - it's tutorial. You are just practical programmer.

Both solutions will work also when you put string inside, or negative numbers ..

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if I truly needed to do that much code when I could use less but I guess it is just another way to do it with more thought involved.

Comment: The OP's function does not work when there are duplicate values in the array where Second_Greatest_Lowest does.

Comment: This answer is quite wrong. OP's solution does not give the correct response: `checker([1,2,3,4,5,11]) // 11,4`

Answer (score 1):

The text of an exercise is misunderstood. They *SHOULD* have ask for a second "unique" number from the beginning and from the end. Then:

1, 1, 1, 1, 1, **2**, 3, 4, **5**, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6

Real answers are: 2, 5. Answers from Your script are 1 and 6. 
So Your answer is OF COURSE great and OK, but **their question is a bit inaccurate**.

But a fact that You have note their mistake, and make a better algorithm, sugest that You can skip to another lesson :).

Comment: They didn't ask for that.. but that would indeed have been a bit more challenging.

Comment: Yeah I know. But according to their proposed answer, this should be the question ;)

Comment: Yes, and their version of the program actually does get it right assuming that it is supposed to be unique.

Comment: So everything is clear now. Good luck, and If You got any other questions feel free to ask. Best regards!

Comment: I should say somethings are clearer... or at least what needs to be clearer should be clearer soon.